# embedding layer index order meaning in Keras Tensorflow

Tags: python, keras, encoding, embedding, tf.keras

I am using Keras Tensorflow to fit Deep Learning models on mixed data input (both numeric and categorical). Categorical covariates have been encoded as numeric using scikit-learn `LabelEncoder` and introduced in the DL using an `Input` layer (one-dimensional). Then, I set `Embedding` Layers using, for example, for a variable with 6 distinct levels:

```
variable_emb = Embedding(input_dim=6,output_dim=1,input_shape=(1,),name='variable_emb_emb')(variable_tensor_input)
```

My question is what is the ordering that Embedding matrix rows follow. Does the i-th row follow the LabelEncoder indexing or it is assigned to the distinct original variable levels according to the sequence in which they occurr in the input data set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by @ad2004, I do a similar experiment while trying to make settings crystal clear. And the result to be illustrated is: **index of embedding layer dirrectly corresponds to the integer representation of your categorical feature.**

Firstly design a simple model with an embedding layer

```
from numpy.random import seed
seed(42)
import tensorflow
tensorflow.random.set_seed(42)

import numpy as np
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=3, output_dim=2, input_length=1, name='embedding'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1))


model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = "adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Then via defining different x_arrays but same y:

```
normal_order = 1 # or 0

if normal_order:
    x_array = np.array([[0],
                        [1],
                        [2],
                        [0],
                        [1],
                        [2]])
if not normal_order:
    x_array = np.array([[2],
                        [1],
                        [0],
                        [2],
                        [1],
                        [0]])

y = np.array([1,1,0,1,1,0])
```

we expect the ***embedding vector of normal_order=1 case should have 0 and 1 to be close to each other***, meanwhile, the ***embedding vector of normal_order=0 case should have 2 and 1 to be close to each other***. Running below codes:

```
model.fit(x = x_array, y, epochs=2000 )

emb_df = pd.DataFrame( model.get_layer('embedding').get_weights()[0]).reset_index()
```

The emb_df for normal_order=1 case is:

```
emb_df
#   index         0         1
#0      0 -0.169505 -0.242161
#1      1 -0.246347 -0.211345
#2      2  0.067879  0.062597
```

while that for normal_order=0 case is:

```
emb_df
#   index         0         1
#0      0  0.104817  0.014432
#1      1 -0.264942 -0.227623
#2      2 -0.179805 -0.162726
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the output rows are simply indexed from 0 to input_dim-1, and whatever integer your LabelEncoder generates for each categorical variate will correspond to the appropriate row.  For instance, if you have 3 categorical variates:  "apple", "pear", "orange" and the LabelEncoder assigns pear=2, orange=0, apple=1, then row 0 of the embedding matrix will be related to "orange", row 1 will be "apple", and row 2 will be "pear."
The below working code snippet shows the idea.  I hope this helps.

```
import numpy as np
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(5, 2))

model.compile('rmsprop', 'mse')
#model.summary()

input_array = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
                        [1, 2, 2]])
output_array = model.predict(input_array)

print('model.get_weights():')
print(model.get_weights())

print('output_array:')
print(output_array)
```